# How to nerf ghasts with nethrar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

[Nethrar](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/10874) is a bukkit plugin to offer a Netherworld experience in SMP. Unfortunately, [worldguard](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/790) doesn't seem to offer an anti-ghast-destruction option like the creeper option that prevents creeper's explosions from destroying blocks (but not players).

> Is there a similar possibility for ghast explosions?

I don't mind them and being (successfully) attacked is part of the game, but the destruction of my unfunished observation deck is a bit annoying...

Comment: Challenge is part of the game! **[Improvise, adapt, and overcome](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091187/quotes)**

Comment: Build your obs. deck out of blocks with >21 [resistance](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Explosion#Blast_Resistance)?

Comment: @Nick thanks for the link. I was hoping for glas to look down... But I could later replace one block at a time, so feel free to post that as an alternative answer

Comment: @Cyclops true for a survival game, but I'd like to have exceptions as in "no hard-to-revert frustrating effects" for this building centred map...

Comment: @Tobias, I'm not familiar with Multiplayer, but can it be set to Peaceful, like Single-player (or does that affect the Nether? And/or, can you download the map to singleplayer, build there (in peaceful), then re-load up to SMP?

Comment: @Cyclops: nice point about using SSP temporarily, I might consider that, thanks. The peaceful setting is currently ignored (I even take damage in the nether), which is also stated as [potential future development](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/10874): `Peaceful mode fix / option for the Nether.` Maybe other nether plugins don't suffer from that, but IIRC they had other issues instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in the latest version of the Nethrar called forcePeacefulNether and if you set the value to true it disables spawning of Ghasts and Zombie Pigmen.

If you would rather not remove the PigZombies and only remove the ghasts, or if you want more fine-tuned controls on mobs you can install [MobLimiter](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-moblimiter-v1-1-set-creature-limits-and-blacklists-617.10804/) on your server.

Comment: good enough to build the platform and turn them on back again later... I'll check MobLimiter later though